# CodeIgniter: Selecting rows with id that corresponds to distinct values in another table

Tags: codeigniter, distinct

I have three separate tables in my DB. One with a list of `companies` and another with a list of `company_categories`. And the last with a like of `categories`. All rows in the `companies` and `categories` table has a unique ID. There are no unique ID's in the `company_categories` table.

This is a sample of what my `companies` table looks like:

```
company_id | company_name     |  logo     |  ....
-----------+------------------+-----------+--------
     5     |  Co 5            |  123.jpg  |  ....
     6     |  Company 6       |  123.jpg  |  ....
     7     |  7's a company   |  234.jpg  |  ....
     8     |  EightCo         |  345.jpg  |  ....
```

This is a sample of what my `categories` table looks like:

```
category_id | category_name 
------------+-----------
      1     |  Blue
      2     |  Red
      3     |  Green
      4     |  Yellow
```

And what my `companies_categories` look like:

```
company_id | category_id
-----------+-----------
     5     |  2
     5     |  3
     6     |  1
     6     |  2
     7     |  1
```

Note: company_id, and category_id both have foreign keys in their relating tables

What I am trying to do is list all companies with a certain category. For example if category 2 is chosen companies 5 and 6 should be returned. If category 4 is chosen, nothing should be displayed. Company 8 should never be displayed (because it has no categories associated with it)

I've attempted to solve this issue by using codeigniter's distinct() function in active record:

```
$this->db->from('company_categories')
->distinct()
->where('category_id', $category_id)
->join('companies', 'companies.company_id = company_categories.company_id')
->select('companies.company_id as co_id companies.logo as co_logo, companies.name as co_name')
->get()->result();
```

but what this actually does is gets distinct `company_id`, `company_logo`, and `company_name`. So if a company (like company 5 and 6) have the same logo only one of those companies will be returned in the result. I would like for both to show. Can this be done using codeigniter's active record?

If not, how can this be done in an SQL query?

Comment: If you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) it would be easier for us to help you

Comment: Thanks for the input @JohnConde. I've created one here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1f24/5 That is how I want my results returned.

Comment: Leave out the distinct. Why add that at all?

Comment: @RickCalder What if (due to a bug) a company is listed twice under a certain category? ie a record with company_id = 5, category_id = 2, and another record with company_id = 5, category_id = 2

Comment: You ensure that doesn't happen via your insert and update queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rick says you don't need the `distinct`. Furthermore you should be selecting from `companies`, and joining on `company_categories` not the other way around.

Your SQL should look like so:

```
SELECT * FROM companies 
JOIN companies_categories 
ON companies.company_id=companies_categories.company_id 
WHERE category_id = 2
```

Updated sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1f24/16/0

In codeigniter:

```
$this->db->select('companies.company_id as co_id, companies.logo as co_logo, companies.name as co_name')
$this->db->where('display_flg',true);
$this->db->join('company_categories', 'companies.company_id = company_categories.company_id');
$query = $this->db->get('companies');
```

Comment: What if there are multiple category_id for a company_id? How will MySQL handle that? Which category_id row will MySQL join with company_id?

Comment: It will only join the one you state in the query, in this case `2`.